# How do I parse a String to a Float?

Tags: json, floating-point, elm

I need to consume a json source that represents `float`s as `string`s* and I can't figure out how.

It is *almost* easy:

```
Json.Decode.map String.toFloat Json.Decode.string
```

However, that produces a `Maybe Float` and I'd prefer it fail altogether if it cant decode the string.

(*) The reason for this is that the real datatype is Decimal, so "1.5" != "1.50". My application doesn't have to care though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either install [`elm-community/json-extra`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/json-extra/4.0.0/) and use [`Json.Decode.Extra.parseFloat`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/json-extra/latest/Json-Decode-Extra#parseFloat)

or just copy its implementation

```
fromMaybe : String -> Maybe a -> Decode.Decoder a
fromMaybe error val =
    case val of
        Just v ->
            Decode.succeed v

        Nothing ->
            Decode.fail error

parseFloat : Decode.Decoder Float
parseFloat =
    Decode.string |> Decode.andThen (String.toFloat >> fromMaybe "failed to parse as float")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option which makes `fromMaybe` unnecessary:

```
floatDecoder : Json.Decoder Float
floatDecoder =
    Json.string |> Json.andThen (String.toFloat >> Maybe.withDefault 0.0 >> Json.succeed)
```

Just in case it helps someone else ;)